# email and age validation need code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this simple form and I would like to validate the date of birth so that the person is over 18 and also the email so that they type the correct email.

**This is my form:**

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<form>
  email <input type="text" id="email"><br>
  phone number <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
  age <input type="text" id="age"><br>
  location 
  <select id="box2" onchnage="calculate()">
    <option value="100">Mcleran</option>
    <option value="200">clear</option>
    <option value="300">brossa</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  no of travelers <input id="box1" type="number" oninput="calculate()" />
  <br>
  total <input id="result" />
</form>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 form validation by using `type="email"` and `type="number"` - this will trigger browsers to show the basic controls/error messages for invalid inputs.

```js
function calculate() {
    //your original method ehre
}
```

```html
<form>
  email <input type="email" id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr" required><br>
  phone number <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
  age <input id="age" type="number" size="3" name="age" min="18" max="199" value="" required><br>
  location 
  <select id="box2" onchnage="calculate()">
    <option value="100">Mcleran</option>
    <option value="200">clear</option>
    <option value="300">brossa</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  no of travelers <input id="box1" type="number" oninput="calculate()" />
  <br>
  total <input id="result" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question please check the green checkbox next to the answer.